# NFC wait for a tag to be placed

Tags: java, android, nfc

I am creating a basic NFC write app. The issue is that I need to find the exact spot on the phone with a tag hold it and press the button (not ideal user experience). I want for user to first press that button then application is waiting for the NFC signal if it finds it within a couple of seconds write to the tag. I've tried to do it with a loop that was trying to write constantly which didn't work (performance wise, it made the app completely unusable due to too many error messages). Could anyone help me with the solution?

```
    try {
        if(myTag ==null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.not_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            write(title + edit_message.getText().toString(), myTag);
            Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.saved), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (FormatException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    myTag =null;
    
    }
```

I've tried to do it with a loop that was trying to write constantly which didn't work (performance wise, it made the app completely unusable due to too many error messages)

Comment: That code is absolutely unreadable

Comment: Is this Android or some other Java setup (It's not Tagged Android or mentioned anything about the platform it is running on)? The question is also not clear and does not actually show any useful NFC type code. Normally with NFC you configure the hardware to do something when a Tag is presented and then wait for the Tag to be presented. You don't try and have a button pressed while the Tag is in range, this poor design. You can have a Button that changes the behaviour of when the Tag comes in to range, usually it changes the behaviour from ignore Tag to doing something.

Comment: Yes, this is android. I'll search for a better design to solve this. Thank you.